# How do I optimize this random pass generator-ish?

Tags: python, optimization

beginner here, I tried making a random password generator but I feel like there is a more efficient way of doing this, pls help, thank you!

```
import random
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 
'q', 'r', 's','t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 
'q', 'r', 's','t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
z = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = y[i].upper()
g = 1
while g == 1:
    a = random.choice(x)
    b = random.choice(y)
    c = random.choice(z)
    d = random.choice(x)
    e = random.choice(y)
    f = random.choice(z)
    h = random.choice(x)
    i = random.choice(y)
    j = random.choice(z)
    k = random.choice(x)
    l = random.choice(y)
    m = random.choice(z)
    n = random.choice(x)
    o = random.choice(y)
    p = random.choice(z)
    break
print(a+b+c+d+e+f+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `random` module has a `choices` and `shuffle` functions, which means that you can pick multiple items at once from those lists (which can easily be just strings which you can btw get from `string` module (built-in)), then concatenate the chosen strings and `shuffle` the resulting string, you can see an example of such password generator [here](https://pastebin.com/Wded79CA)

Comment: The code as it is now can be replaced by `while True: pass`.

Answer (score 2):

First, simplify your string creation:

```
import string

# this will give you all upper and lower case letters and numbers 0-10
all_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
```

Then, just user `random.choice` over a range of `all_chars`:

```
# the length of your string will be range(x) - 1
print(''.join(random.choice(all_chars) for i in range(10)))
```

outputs:

```
bHGsT5swSv
```

So the complete code:

```
import string
import random

all_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
# 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'

# 9 character output
print(''.join(random.choice(all_chars) for i in range(10)))

# or as suggested by the comments using unpacking
print(*random.choices(all_chars, k=10), sep='')
```

Comment: `print(''.join(random.choices(all_chars, k=10)))`, why use the `for` loop?, for printing you could also use `print(*random.choices(all_chars, k=10), sep='')` (which coincidentally is the same length as the other line)

Comment: that does look nice, I just didn't think about it! I'll edit in

Comment: I wasn't suggesting unpacking (it is also the second line I have suggested and only for using in `print` really), I was suggesting not using a `for` loop because it is unnecessary